# is it possible to retrieve a password from a (partial) MD5 hash?

Tags: hash, passwords, md5, brute-force, rainbowattack

Suppose I have only the first 16 characters of a MD5 hash. If I use brute force attack or rainbow tables or any other method to retrieve the original password, how many compatible candidates have I to expect? 1? (I do not think) 10, 100, 1000, 10^12? Even a rough answer is welcome (for the number, but please be coherent with hash theory and methodology).

Comment: AFAIK hashes are irreversible theoretically, even though if you can brute force it practically , it shall take months on normal PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of MD5 is 16 *bytes* (128 bits). I suppose that you are talking about an hexadecimal representation, hence as 32 *characters*. Thus, "16 characters" means "64 bits". You are considering MD5 with its output truncated to 64 bits.

MD5 accepts inputs up to *2<sup>64</sup>* bits in length; assuming that MD5 behaves as a random function, this means that the *2<sup>18446744073709551616</sup>* possible input strings will map more or less uniformly among the *2<sup>64</sup>* outputs, hence the average number of candidates for a given output is about *2<sup>18446744073709551552</sup>*, which is close to *10<sup>5553023288523357112.95</sup>*.

However, if you consider that you can *find* at least one candidate, then this means that the space of possible passwords that you consider is much reduced. A [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) is a special kind of precomputed table which accepts a compact representation (at the expense of a relatively expensive lookup procedure), but if it covers *N* passwords, then this means that, at some point, someone could apply the hash function *N* times. In practice, this severely limits the size *N*. Assuming *N=2<sup>60</sup>* (which means that the table builder had about one hundred NVidia GTX 580 GPU and could run them for six months; also, the table will use quite a lot of hard disks), then, on average, only 1/16th of 64-bit outputs have a matching password in the table. For those passwords which are in the table, there is a 93.75% probability that there is no other password in the table which leads to the same output; if you prefer, if you find a matching password, then you will find, on average, 0.0625 other candidates (i.e. most of the time, no other candidate).

In brief, the answer to your question depends on the size *N* of the space of possible passwords that you consider (those which were covered during rainbow table construction); but, in practice with Earth-based technology, if you can find *one* matching password for a 64-bit output, chances are that you will not be able to find another (although there are are really many others).

Answer (score 1):

You should never ever be able to get a password from a partial hash.